# update my join on temporary table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table called leaderboard

which I create

```
 create temporary table leaderboard 
 (
     rank integer primary key auto_increment, 
     score_id integer, 
     game varchar(65), 
     user_id integer
)

select 
     id, 
     highscore, 
     playername 
from 
     players 
order by 
     highscore desc
```

This is fine but am now trying to update the table with a join in the id.

```
UPDATE players 
SET players.rank = leaderboard.rank 
FROM players 
JOIN leaderboard ON players.id = leaderboard.id
```

but get an error in the mysql? And pointers would be good

error is

> ...the right syntax to use near 'FROM players JOIN leaderboard ON
>   players.id = leaderboard.id' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE players 
JOIN leaderboard ON players.id = leaderboard.id
SET players.rank = leaderboard.rank
```

Mysql syntax is different from tsql. That style would work on mssql